# ack.pl tool and ack.pl flags + how to ignore files with S attr

Tags: linux, filesystems, grep, file-attributes, ack

I am using the ack.pl tool in order to search string or IP’s in files

The official site of ack.pl is - http://beyondgrep.com/documentation/

Example of ack.pl CLI ( want to find the string STRING_TO_FIND in files under /etc )

```
  /tmp/ack.pl -Q -a -l --max-count=1  STRING_TO_FIND  /etc
```

But sometimes ack.pl is stuck on files as:

```
  ---S--l---   1 root     root          0 Mar 10 04:25  /opt/POP_lock
```

From MAN paget "S" attr mean that:

Using an upper-case "S" instead of a lower-case "s" tells the filesystem to immediately write the file to disk, instead of storing it in a buffer. (Note also, that we left the "s" attribute this time, so that we now have two attributes set for this file.)

So my question is:

How ack.pl can ignore the files with “S” , 
Or what the ack.pl flags that shuld ignore this files with “S” ?

Comment: For future readers of this question, it was answered over here on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982968/ack-pl-tool-and-ack-pl-flags-how-to-ignore-type-of-files

Comment: Also at Unix&Linux: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/189289/80216